# How to remove specific word from a string in CSV(in Python)?

Tags: python, string, csv

I want to rewrite a CSV row, if a string starts with 'a' or 'the'. We may use the `string.startswith()` for this purpose.

The problem may be grossly stated like this:

```
if string.startswith('A' or 'The')
  remove 'a' and 'the'; keep the rest of the string; rewrite the row
```

Suppose the CSV is:

```
ID    Book                Author
1.    A Study in Scarlet  Conan Doyle
2.    Aboltabol           Sukumar Roy
3.    The Bible           Matthew
```

It should look like:

```
    ID    Book                Author
    1.    Study in Scarlet    Conan Doyle
    2.    Aboltabol           Sukumar Roy
    3.    Bible               Matthew
```

How do we do this in Python?

Comment: Neither of the examples look like *Comma-Separated Values* (though the delimiter does not strictly need to be comma). They resemble the string representation of pandas DataFrames, though.

Comment: Do you already have code to read CSV file? If you have, please provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular expressions module

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^(A|The)\s+(.+)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def process(word):
    w = pattern.match(word)
    return w.group(2) if w else word

process('A Study in Scarlet')  # 'Study in Scarlet'
process('Aboltabol')  # 'Aboltabol'
process('The Bible')  # 'Bible'
```

Though if you need performance, `startswith` + `split` is faster.

Comment: Thanks. It's working if `print` is used in place of `return`.